# Dynamically use of model to send relationship value in a view in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, eloquent

I am working on a bookmarking type of websites and want to show links related to their respective category on the category page. One link can only have one category.

I have created the model and view but having problem with the code of the controller to get data dynamically.

Links table

```
    {
        Schema::create('links', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->text('link');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('votes');
            $table->dateTime('submitted_at');
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
```

Categories table

```
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Category Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
       protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug', 'status',
    ];
     public function links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Links');
    }
}
```

Links Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Links extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'link', 'title', 'description', 'submitted_at', 'category_id','votes',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories');
    }
}
```

Categories controller

```
public function index($slug)
    {
        $getcategoryid = DB::table('categories')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
        $catid = $getcategoryid[0]->id;
        $catlinks=new \App\Category;
        $catlinks=$catlinks::find(1)->Links;
        return $catlinks;
```

The problem is I want `find(1)` to be dynamic according to the page. like if I can use $catid like `find($catid)` or something?

How can I get data to a category page if is has links then show and if not show a message no link found. like using `count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to load the links of a single category given a slug, you can do that like this:

```php
// Do not forget to add this line after the namespace declaration
use App\Category;

public function index($slug)
{
    return Category::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail()->links;
}
```

But a nicer way would be to set up route model binding for your category model.

To do so, in your Category class put this method:

```php
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

**Important:** in your route file, make sure to replace the `{slug}` parameter of your route with `{category}` otherwise route model binding would not work at all.

Then in your controller class the index function would become:

```php
public function index(Category $category)
{
    return $category->links;
}
```

You can read more about route model binding in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

---

#### Updated answer

If you want to customize the response when the category doesn't exists you can do like the code below (in this case without using route model binding).

```php
// Do not forget to add this line after the namespace declaration
use App\Category;

public function index($slug)
{
    $category = Category::whereSlug($slug)->first();

    if (! $category) {
        return response()->json([]);
    }

    return response()->json($category->links);
}
```

Comment: Hi @mdexp this worked properly but how can I echo "No links found" in case of there are no links in selected category? an empty array? [ ]

Answer (score 0):

remember:

instead of `\App\Category` or `\App\Links` you can include it top of controller like this `use App\Category;` and `use App\Links;`

instead of

```
    $getcategoryid = DB::table('categories')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
    $catid = $getcategoryid[0]->id;
```

use

```
$catid = Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

and instead of :

```
$catlinks=new \App\Category;
$catlinks=$catlinks::find(1)->Links;
return $catlinks;
```

use

```
return catlinks = $catid->links;
```

this code return all links belong to category

if you want to pass this data to view

use

```
return view('exampleview',compact('catid'));
```

and in view you can check catid has links or not

```
@if($catid->links->count() > 0)
has link
@else
no link
@endif
```

Comment: This one is giving error ````return $catlinks = $catid->links;````  "Trying to get property 'links' of non-object"

Comment: @NitinGandhi because of ```first()->id``` , I removed ```->id``` check it again to solve

Answer (score 0):

To get links that belong to a category with `$slug` you can do:

```
$links = Link::whereHas('category', function($query) use ($slug) {
    $query->where('slug', $slug);
})->get();
```

You can do it with a JOIN too, but this is simpler and clearer.

Also, when you have models, you don't need to use `DB::table(...)`, and you don't have to make a model instance manually. The instance will be created behind the scenes when you do `Link::whereHas`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is a bit all over the place, so for example in Laravel its recommended to keep all Class names singular, but you have used Links instead of Link.  2nd your database structure could be better, for example when you use relationships the column type should match the id of the linking table, so if the id is a `bigIncrements`, the linking category_id field should be an `unsignedBigInteger`, also utilise foreign keys.

To try to help you

```
public function index($slug)
{
        $category = \App\Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
        $catlinks = $category->links;
        return view('name.of.view', ['links' => $catlinks]);
}
```

If you learn Route Model Binding you can also do it like so

```
public function index(\App\Category $category)
{
        $catlinks = $category->links;
        return view('name.of.view', ['links' => $catlinks]);
}
```

Then in your view you can use the @forelse blade directive like so

```
@forelse($links as $link)
    Do something with the link
@empty
    Message to display if empty
@endforelse
```

But what I would really recommend is learn Laravel, the docs are extremely good.  THen you can do this in your controller:-

```
public function index(\App\Category $category)
{
        return view('name.of.view', ['category' => $category]);
}
```

Then in your view you can use the @forelse blade directive like so

```
@forelse($category->links as $link)
    Do something with the link
@empty
    Message to display if empty
@endforelse
```

Unfortunately, there is no way of getting a better knowledge and understanding of the framework than to put the time into read and use the docs